# Cannot sign out from devise when javascript is disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am test proofing my website when JS is disabled. And got a funny error.

It happens on the landing page when a `Client` is logged in and tries to log out. (`Client` being a Devise model)

My navbar has this logout link :

```
<li><%= link_to 'exit', destroy_client_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
```

Everything goes fine when JS is enabled but when JS is disabled I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ClientsController#show
Couldn't find Client with 'id'=sign_out
```

This happens on the clients_controller.rb (I do have a `clients` folder with all devise controllers in there : `confirmations_controller.rb`, `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`, ... but I also have a `clients_controller.rb` file with the classic REST : show, ... )

The error happens in this controller in the show action :

```
def show
    if client_signed_in? && current_client.id == Client.find(params[:id]).id then
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I am checking here if the current logged-in `client` is matching the client that is passed in the navbar, so only the logged-in client can see their very profile ...

Though The controller cannot perform the check it seems ..

**My question : Why the sign-out sends me to the Client controller and why enabling or disabling JS has a role in here ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because devise uses the `delete` HTTP verb by default and this trick is dependent on `jquery-ujs` to work.

```
= link_to .... method: :delete
```

According to the `jquery-ujs` [docs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) this does among other things...

> make non-GET requests from hyperlinks;

You can change that in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
# change :delete to :get
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

and then your link_to should be

```
= link_to 'exit', destroy_client_session_path
```

Comment: Damn. works like a charm!! thanks.  Though can you confirm this is the Devise code that triggers JS when the delete method is called... Cause I guess delete is just an http query that is independant from JS